Good method for sorting out samples with/without oscillation pattern in panel data?
I have biomed panel data. Some variables are time series (blood tests from ~320 participants) with few samples (~20-100), others are fixed over time (age, height...). There is an intervention at some point in time, and I want to study its effects on the time series. Some series graphically seem to present an oscillation pattern immediately after intervention (around 0 on the X axis, reason unknown), while others do not. What would be a good way of isolating the oscillating series from the non-oscillating ones to investigate what's going on ? I am currently trying to use the 1st and 2nd derivatives, but getting nowhere.


Can you share some examples of oscillations? The answer depends probably on what they are like; all of equal frequency, how much noise, how long they are, etcetera.
